# How to find all methods in assembly that instantiate object of class X?

Tags: c#, configuration, code-analysis

Interesting question here: In my current project we're using a custom performance monitoring suite that is very config-heavy (it uses Perfmon so we have to manually register each performance counter. There is one performance counter for each method that we monitor, and there are a lot of those).

I was wondering if there are any tools that would, say, allow me to analyse the project assembly, find all methods that instantiate an instance of class XClass, then write them out to a file? This would allow me to cut down the amount of manual config I need to do by a large margin.

Thanks, Ed

EDIT

Sorry, the 'write them to a file' thing was a little contrived: really I need to reformat them with some extra data and write them in a config-specific XML format. This would be best if I can code it up so it can be set as a build task (so I don't have to run it manually) and any future changes can be made easily and documented etc.

Comment: Hi Ed, could you either request more informations, or accept an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Open the assembly in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (the free version is fine); find the type (<kbd>F3</kbd>), then bring up the anaylyzer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and expand the "Instantiated By" node.

Then right-click on the "Instantiated By" node itself and click copy; for example:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    Depends On
    Used By
    Exposed By
    Instantiated By
        SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.GetHashHelper(String, SqlConnectionStringBuilder&, DbConnectionPoolIdentity&, String&, String) : SqlConnectionContainerHashHelper
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder() : DbConnectionStringBuilder
        System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider.Initialize(String, NameValueCollection) : Void
        System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.CreatePartitionInfo(String) : IPartitionInfo
        System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore+SqlPartitionInfo.get_TracingPartitionString() : String
        System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore+SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to write code to automate your task, it's easy to do it with [Mono.Cecil](http://github.com/jbevain/cecil). As an example, this code searches through all the methods of the top level types of an assembly for the instantiation of a class Foo.Bar.Baz:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;

// ...

static void SearchMethod (MethodDefinition method)
{    
    foreach (var instruction in method.Body.Instructions) {
        if (instruction.OpCode != OpCodes.Newobj)
            continue;

        var constructor = (MethodReference) instruction.Operand;
        if (constructor.DeclaringType.FullName != "Foo.Bar.Baz")
            continue;

        Console.WriteLine ("new Foo.Bar.Baz in {0}", method.FullName);
    }
}

static void Main ()
{
    var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule ("Foo.Bar.dll");
    var methods = module.Types.SelectMany (t => t.Methods).Where (m => m.HasBody);
    foreach (var method in methods)
         SearchMethod (method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It's a static analysis tool with a very powerful query language: CQL ([Code Query Language](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL)).

**Update**

NDepend has a console application that can be prodded for automation (e.g. for use in a build systems) and can output reports to file.

An example query to find methods which instantiate a defined type:

> SELECT METHODS WHERE CreateA "MyNamespace.MyClass"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your design so that they use a factory instead, such that the factory is responsible for the extra bookkeeping.

That said, you can look in the System.Reflection namespace, (from memory), where the Assembly class is used.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my design: this amount of config is overkill in my opinion but the powers that be have decreed, and so it will be. I've managed to drop a lot of the more intrusive code snippets that were supporting this functionality, but the config is more difficult to remove, and needs to be done and sent to perfmon before the app can be run.

Comment: I was suggesting that it should be autogenerated as far as possible, and where not possible, change the design of new code so that it will be.